# want to run exportfs in container, what need to mount into container?

Tags: centos, centos7, nfs

I want to run `exportfs -a` command, but instead to run directly on host, I want to run in a privileged container on the host. It means I need to mount some files/directories into containers, so `exportfs -a` will take effect on hosts.

I mount the following:

- `/etc/exports` and `/etc/exports.d`
- all directories listed in `/etc/exports` and `etc/exports.d`
- `/var/lib/nfs/etab`

But when I modify `/etc/exports` and run `exportfs -a`, nothing changes in `/var/lib/nfs/etab`

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To mount `/var/lib/nfs` instead of `/var/lib/nfs/etab` can solve this problem.

It is a permission issue that `/var/lib/nfs` should be writable.